# File manager issues since upgrade to 2.6.1

Tags: file-manager

I recently upgraded to 2.6.1 and i have had a few buggy issues in file manager since. Firstly i get a white screen of death on file sync and also when i click on a image link in the file manager table the light box is gone and it opens the image in the browser.
Thanks for any help

Comment: You may have a corrupt file in your themes folder. Can you download EE again and re-upload the themes folder. Backup your current themes folder first (especially for third_party and site_themes).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was caused by Generate HTTP Page Headers being set as on in output and debugging.
This caused a real delay in the full page load and this caused the issues file manager.Turning it off and this sorted my problems